# Is it genitive case in this sentence? Then why doesn't it get the genitive article?

Tags: article, genitive

> Das ist **eine Art ehrenamtliches Engagement**.

This is translated to English as:

> That is **a kind of volunteer work**.

That is why I think that *eine Art ehrenamtliches Engagement* is genitive. But why doesn't it take genitive article as:

> Das ist eine Art **des** ehrenamtliches Engagement.

Comment: Your last sentence should be: "Das ist eine Art des ehrenamtliche***n*** Engagement***s***"

Answer (score 3):

There are two kinds of phrasing for the intended meaning:

> Das ist eine Art (des) ehrenamtlichen Engagements.

This one would be used in writing and shows the genitive you expect.

The other, more informal:

> Das ist eine Art Ehrenamt/ehrenamtliches Engagement.

In this case you have two nominatives, since *Engagement* serves as a collective specification (see [canoonet](http://www.canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Nomen/Bedeutung/index.html#Anchor-Gattungsbezeichnungen-35882)).

Comment: So even in writing *des* is not necessary, because you put it in parentheses?

Comment: @Sasan: Yes, in this case the article is optional (and one could also use the indefinite article), but this is a pecularity of *Art*.

Comment: *Art* works nearly the same as *Glas*. *Ein Glas Bier, bitte.* — *Kölsch ist eine Art Bier.*

Answer (score 2):

`Das ist eine Art ehrenamtliches Engagement.` - That's normal nominative. You can even remove `eine Art` and get the same sentence structure: `Das ist ehrenamtliches Engagement.` That you can translate it using genitive does not imply that it is genitive in German, too.

`Das ist ein Art des ehrenamtlichen Engagements.` - That, however, is genitive. But it's a different structure, anyway.

Comment: Two nominative in a row without a comma? When does such structure happen?

Answer (score 1):

"Das" is not only an article here. It refers to something not mentioned here. It can be substituted by "dies" or "welches". Isn´t it possible to substitute "that" in the English translation? The linguists amongs us can explain it better. I´m just nativ German.

The 's' is not genitiv, it is for neutral nouns.

> "Ein schönes Haus." "Gutes Essen" ..."ehrenamtliches Engagement"

Das Beispiel mit Genitiv ist nicht korrekt. Es muss heißen:

> Das ist eine Art des ehrenamtliche**n** Engagement**s**.

This sentence would change the meaning a little. While the fist sentence makes the action to volunteer work, the second version explains volunteer work and makes the action part of it.